# How to hide and show <td> which is a part of IEnumerable model tabel in html list View

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

This is a @model IEnumerable
and   is depends under loop @Foreach(var item in model)

i have some  as a button , and  i want to hide one and show another 
second button   is not displaying

```
<style>
    .clv1{
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<td id="cv" class="con1">
    <input type="submit" id="convrt" name="convrt" value="Add To INv No:- @ViewBag.NewINVNo1" class="convrt btn btn-success " />
</td>
<td id="clv" class="clv1">
    <input type="submit" id="cancel" name="cancel" value="Cancel this " class="convt11 btn btn-danger btn-group-sm " />
</td>
```

Here i want to hide convert button and show cancel button

I tried this in jQuery

```
$(this).closest('tr td:nth-child(9)').hide();
$(this).closest('tr td:nth-child(10)').show();
```

but child 9 is hide properly but he cant show child 10 
need help

Answer (score 0):

if you have unique id, then you directly apply hide and show.

```
$('#convrt').hide();
$('#cancel').show();
```

Comment: no ,but i just  change belittle  ,main think is idea $(this).closest("tr").find('#convt').hide();
    $(this).closest('tr').find('#cansel').show();